# Circle yandex maps api 2.1

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, карты, геолокация

Как сделать так, чтобы после определения местоположения добавить к нему окружность с радиусом 1 км?

Яндекс карты API 2.1

Answer (score 3):

В их песочницу заходишь и там же склеиваешь из примеров.

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55, 34],
            zoom: 10
        });
    // Сравним положение, вычисленное по ip пользователя и
    // положение, вычисленное средствами браузера.
    geolocation.get({
        provider: 'yandex',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {
    //console.log(result.geoObjects.position[0],result.geoObjects.position[1]);//проверка координат
        // Красным цветом пометим положение, вычисленное через ip.
        result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redCircleIcon');
        result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.set({
            balloonContentBody: 'Мое местоположение'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
                     // Создаем круг.
    var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
        // Координаты центра круга.
        [result.geoObjects.position[0], result.geoObjects.position[1]],
        // Радиус круга в метрах.
        10000
    ], {
        // Описываем свойства круга.
        // Содержимое балуна.
        balloonContent: "Радиус круга - 10 км",
        // Содержимое хинта.
        hintContent: "Подвинь меня"
    }, {
        // Задаем опции круга.
        // Включаем возможность перетаскивания круга.
        draggable: true,
        // Цвет заливки.
        // Последний байт (77) определяет прозрачность.
        // Прозрачность заливки также можно задать используя опцию "fillOpacity".
        fillColor: "#DB709377",
        // Цвет обводки.
        strokeColor: "#990000",
        // Прозрачность обводки.
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        // Ширина обводки в пикселях.
        strokeWidth: 1
    });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);// Добавляем круг на карту.
    });
    geolocation.get({
        provider: 'browser',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        // Синим цветом пометим положение, полученное через браузер.
        // Если браузер не поддерживает эту функциональность, метка не будет добавлена на карту.
        result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueCircleIcon');
        myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
    });
}
```

И доводишь до нужного вида и функциональности.

Comment: Спасибо получилось!